# SQL hierarchical query replacing XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, .net-4.0

I'm working on a very complex ASP.NET Web application. The menu is a Treeview which gathers its content out of a XML document. The XML gets generated and gets filled with data out of a SQL database. The data in the SQL database is stored in multiple tables which have dependencies to eachother. So the way to the final menu looks like that.

SQL DB -> XML -> Treeview (Menu)

My question is the following: Is there a way to avoid the step to 'xml' and  read the data hierarchically out of the database into the treeview? Or is there another way to make a treeview directly out of databes data?

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0, SQL SERVER 2008 and the usual .NET Treeview control.

Any help apreciated

Comment: did you consider using `FOR XML AUTO` or `FOR XML RAW` in this case?

Comment: I had a look over that. Thany you for your comment. Unfortunately, in my situation, that would have gotten too complicated. Thats why I've decided to go the c# way... But for others this might be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can find your solution here

```
http://aspalliance.com/732_Display_Hierarchical_Data_with_TreeView_in_ASPNET_20
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I later found a similar tutorial in c# maby this will help somone soetime. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-bind-multiple-sql-server-tables-with-a-treeview-in-a/